Trouble getting multiple SMB windows folders to mount
I have already mounted one network folder from my windows PC following the guide in this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0B8lPKRe0x0&t=303s
when trying to repeat the process for mounting a second folder I receive an error in the terminal saying
mount: /etc/fstab: parse error at line 16 -- ignored

Line 16 of my fstab file is the last entry shown below. I have made a new folder in the documents directory, as I did with the previous folder shown in Line 15, and then added Line 16 of the fstab file using the command
sudo nano /etc/fstab

here is a copy of my fstab file:
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-LVM-Kjee4DpkIj92JY8lk8UEb7HJd9W8tVkgGLgObedufVthytvPpaNl5qhK4sfeEMp1 / ext4 defaults 0 1
# /boot was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/7108698c-3f4f-4470-844f-0facae47d584 /boot ext4 defaults 0 1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/01EF-0190 /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1
/swap.img       none    swap    sw      0       0
//192.168.4.53/Emulators /home/c10/Documents/EmulatorsWINNETWK cifs credentials=/home/c10/.smbcred,iocharset=utf8,gid=1000,uid=1000,file_mode=07>
//192.168.4.53/Misc. Games /home/c10/Documents/PCGamesWINNETWK cifs credential=/home/c10/.smbcred,iocharset=utf8,gid=1000,uid=1000,file_mode=077>


One obvious issue is the space character in Misc. Games - you can replace it with octal \040 i.e. Misc.\040Games. See for example What is causing the "mount: /etc/fstab: parse error at line 16 -- ignored" error?

I have just tried that and it states no such file or directory, the folder is set to shared with full control permissions for all users through windows file explorer.

After editing the file properly, I am recieving a prompt when running sudo mount -a for a password. I have entered the password from my smbcred file and recieve this error:          mount error(22): Invalid argument
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)

... credential should be credentials maybe?

That worked thank you so much!

This question is similar to: What is causing the "mount: /etc/fstab: parse error at line 16 -- ignored" error?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
